# Get a debug screen in flask when an exception occurs with AJAX

Tags: python, flask

I absolutely LOVE flask's debug page that shows up when an exception is raised and you're in debug mode.  However, I develop a lot of applications that make heavy use of AJAX, and unfortunately you don't get that beautiful debugging when the exception occurs from an AJAX request.  You just get a `500 Internal Server Error` printed to the browser's console.

I understand why you don't get the page - because the page isn't reloading - but still, I want to ask if there's a way to get a really nice page like that in the event of an exception in an AJAX call.

Comment: You should be able to see it in the browser's developer tools, against the network request corresponding to the Ajax call.

Comment: I would like access to the interactive debug console that has all the local variables of the context where I can type in Python code.  Is it possible to get that?  I'm using Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: @J-bob: You'd have to replay the request with a normal browser; if your AJAX request is a GET, simply copy the request URL into a new tab.